# Sprinboot: I am getting java.lang.StackOverflowError when trying to pass an object to my model attribute

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to send my employee entity to the view, but i keep getting a stack overflow error.

This is the controller which i pass the employee model.

```
public String ToShowDashboard(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

    Employee employee = (Employee) this.cookieService.getStoredObject("branded", request);

    model.addAttribute("employee", employee );

    if (employee.getPosition().equals(Employee.POSITION.ADMIN)) {

        return "designers/dashboard";

    }else {return "designers/dashboard2";}

}
```

this is the EmployeeEnity class

```
 @Entity
public class Employee extends DefaultEntity {


    public enum POSITION {ADMIN, NON_ADMIN}

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @Email
    private String email;

    private String password;

    private boolean activated = false;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private POSITION position;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fashion_brand_id")
    private FashionBrand fashionBrand;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Task> tasks;

    private double rating;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public FashionBrand getFashionBrand() {
        return fashionBrand;
    }

    public void setFashionBrand(FashionBrand fashionBrand) {
        this.fashionBrand = fashionBrand;
    }

    public double getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(double rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public List<Task> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }

    public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }

    public POSITION getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(POSITION position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public boolean isActivated() {
        return activated;
    }

    public void setActivated(boolean activated) {
        this.activated = activated;
    }
}
```

and this is the error i keep getting

```
 Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:986)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:167)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
Root Cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.checkPackageAccess(ReflectUtil.java:164)
    sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.isPackageAccessible(ReflectUtil.java:195)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:164)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printObject(JavaScriptUtils.java:353)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.print(JavaScriptUtils.java:184)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printKeyValue(JavaScriptUtils.java:346)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printMap(JavaScriptUtils.java:337)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printObject(JavaScriptUtils.java:365)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.print(JavaScriptUtils.java:184)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printCollection(JavaScriptUtils.java:322)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.print(JavaScriptUtils.java:173)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printKeyValue(JavaScriptUtils.java:346)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printMap(JavaScriptUtils.java:337)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printObject(JavaScriptUtils.java:365)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.print(JavaScriptUtils.java:184)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printKeyValue(JavaScriptUtils.java:346)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printMap(JavaScriptUtils.java:337)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printObject(JavaScriptUtils.java:365)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.print(JavaScriptUtils.java:184)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printCollection(JavaScriptUtils.java:322)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.print(JavaScriptUtils.java:173)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printKeyValue(JavaScriptUtils.java:346)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printMap(JavaScriptUtils.java:337)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printObject(JavaScriptUtils.java:365)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.print(JavaScriptUtils.java:184)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printKeyValue(JavaScriptUtils.java:346)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printMap(JavaScriptUtils.java:337)
    org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printObject(JavaScriptUtils.java:365)
```

Please what can be the cause of this issue, as the error messages are not that detailed .

Finally this is my thymeleaf template:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="full-height" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"></meta>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"></meta>
    <title>Material Design Bootstrap</title>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->


</head>


<body>



<div id="main">



    <div class="container-fluid pt-4">




<div class="fixed-action-btn" style="bottom: 45px; right: 24px;">
    <a class="btn-floating btn-lg red">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
    </a>

    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><a class="btn-floating green" onclick="showAddEmployeeModal()"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></a></li>
        <li><a class="btn-floating blue" onclick="showViewEmployeeModal()"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript"  src="../js/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->

<script type="text/javascript"  src="../js/vendor/knockout/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/vendor/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/vendor/datatables/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="../js/vendor/branded/model/Designer/DesignerDashboardModel.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">


    $(document).ready(function() {

        /*<![CDATA[*/

        var Object = {};

        console.log(/*[[${employee}]]*/);

        Object.employee = /*[[${employee}]]*/ 'default';

        Object.fashionBrand = /*[[${fashionBrand}]]*/ 'default';

        ko.applyBindings(new designerDashboardModel(Object));


        /*]]>*/
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show your thymeleaf template. The error is coming from the view rendering.

Comment: @Strelok i have added the template, but removed alot of the body so that i  can post it, below in page, i tried parsing the models into a js variable

Comment: @Strelok i noticed that is i remove the employee entity and add somthing simple like a string or and int, it works successfully

Comment: I think that Object.employee = /* ... */; doesn't work.You try to assign a object to a key of a Key-Value-Pair-Collection. I have mixed feelings about that. Try 1.) to assign a single attribute or 2.) try to define Object.employee as object ( = {}) first. Doesn't know if the 2nd option works, but give it a shot.

Comment: @Flocke it doesnt work,  i removed  the conversion from JAVA to JS Script, but even without that script, it still crashes.

Comment: Let me guess Your `Employee` relates to `Task` which relates to `Employee` which.... Your entity mapping results in a circular reference.

Comment: ^ - that's the problem.  You need to exclude attributes which can cause a circular reference.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes  i used a one to Many mapping

Comment: @Metroids then how is it possible to have a oneToMany relationship without making creating a circular reference. the only way i am guessing is making the mapping uni directional

Comment: I would say remove the list of tasks from the `Employee` and rather use an additional query to retrieve the tasks.